# Define SQL Server connection using ODBC provider

Tags: sql-server, airflow, odbc

I'm having a hard time getting a connection to test as "ok" in airflow UI. I have SQL Server running on wsl2. Airflow also on WSL2. Have tried airflow's SQL Server provider and then moved to ODBC provider after reading some recent posts saying that's the way to go. So now I'm just trying to get a connection set up using ODBC provider.

Not currently using docker.  Airflow is installed using a python venv and sql server is installed direclty on the WSL2 VM.

But I keep getting an error like this when I test:

> ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

I reviewed the odbc.py hook provider code's comments and updated the airflow.cfg as mentioned there to allow passing the driver via "extra" field in the UI's connection definition. But still no dice.

Can confirm the database is up and the user I'm testing with is able to access and query it.

Can confirm that `odbcinst -q -d` shows I have ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server installed, and driver 18 also, but specifying either one of them in "extra" json values in airflow connection for definition page neither seems to work and I get this same error above.

Can confirm I'm putting the database name in schema, and the host is localhost, although I also tried 127.0.0.1.

Install drivers and dependencies according to airflow and Microsoft documentation.  Expected the ODBC connection to test as "OK".  Configured airflow.cfg providers.obdc to allow driver in extra = true, according to odbc.py provider code comments, expected the connection to test "OK".  But still it does not work.

Comment: Unsure of the ODBC problem, but I realized that airflow blanks out the password on the UI's connections definition after saving, and when you click "test", it does not apparently pull the password from the database, you have to actually re-type it in, then click test, and then presumably save again to be sure.

I think this may have been the entire issue, but will re-try the ODBC approach again tomorrow.  But I got the sql server provider connection type working simply by making sure the password field wasn't blank when clicking test.